# Return names of natural points of interest

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the google maps javascript v3 api, I'm trying to copy the "What's here" functionality currently present on the official google maps website. It works, aside from the but one difference with the official site seems that it won't return lakes or oceans as result.

Is this possible with any of the google apis or do you have to defer to other databases for this? (Which would be a shame!)

An example would be "Lac de Nino" (Corsica, France) , I can search for it & the api returns the correct results, however, providing the geocoder or places api with the lat lng will either return the address or closest natural park, but not the name of the lake.

I know there are other services, such as geonames, but to ease implementation, I was curious if it's possible with any google api currently available.